# Use a sequential argument to show that if $c \neq 0, f$ does not have a limit at $c$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here, $f$ is a real valued function given by

$f= x, x\in \mathbb Q$

$=0, x\in \mathbb {R-Q} $

I'm trying to prove this by using the sequential divergence criterion.

Let $c\neq 0 \in \mathbb Q. \Rightarrow \exists$ a sequence $(x_n)$ of irrational numbers that converges to $c$.

So, $f(x_n)=0, \forall n\in \mathbb N \Rightarrow lim(f(x_n))=0$

But $f(c)=c$.

I'm stuck here. I needed to show that $f(x_n)$ does not have a limit in $\mathbb R$ or it doesn't converge to a given $L$. I don't know where to take it from here.

Comment: You've shown the limit doesn't equal $f(c).$ Relax, you're done.

Comment: @zhw but isn't that the criterion for continuity? I'm a little confused there...

Comment: You're right, my mistake. So let's think about a sequence $x_n \to c$ such that  $x_n$ is rational for odd $n,$ irrational for even $n.$

Comment: @zhw. I cannot think of a sequence like that... Can I construct it like that? $(x_n)=c, x \in \mathbb Q$, where $c \in \mathbb Q$, and $(x_n)=d, x \in \mathbb {R-Q}$, where $d \in \mathbb {R-Q}$?

Comment: @Diya , for proofs, it is not necessary to explicitly mention an example of a sequence like that. But if you want to think about a specific one, it can be $(3, \pi , 2.4, e, 5.7, \pi ^2, ...)$